# Force input number decimal places natively

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to force an `<input type="number" step="0.01" />` to always have 2 decimals to enter accounting data.

I've managed to do that using JavaScript

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', force2decimals);

function force2decimals(event) {
 event.target.value = Number(Math.round(event.target.value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" id="input" value="1.00" />
```

Is there any way to handle this natively?

I know about the `step` attribute, the "duplicate answer" doesn't reply to my question.

Comment: Use `input` event...

Comment: Take a look at the `pattern` attribute, such as `pattern="\d+\.\d\d"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `pattern` attribute doesn't work with `number`-typed inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by this:

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', force2decimals);

function force2decimals(event) {
 event.target.value = parseFloat(event.target.value).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" id="input" value="1.00" />
```

There is no way to do this "natively" in HTML5.

Comment: no need to check value length , it will automatically format
val = parseFloat(event.target.value).toFixed(2);

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, Yes. my first answer was with a line. But, when we have a number like 1.10, it converts it to 1.1 . So, I wrote the extra codes to always keep it in 2 decimals

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, I reverted the answer and it's working fine :)

Comment: Isn't there an HTML way of doing it?

Comment: @YannBertrand, no. HTML acts as a mathematical view. You want to act as an accountant. So, you have to do it manually. That's the way I recommend

Comment: I hope it will come in the future then! Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @YannBertrand, no problem. I wish so

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
function force2decimals(event) {
  var value = $(event).val();
  var format_val = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
  $(event).val(format_val);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" id="input" onchange="force2decimals(this)" value="1.00" />
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: there is no jQuery tag for the question. That means he wants it by JavaScript. Not jQuery

Comment: In this question, there is no restriction to use jQuery so why we do not use jQuery if it will easy and in this question there is no jQuery tag that ok but if question provider miss tag then we can not answer using related something?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Yes, that is the current protocol. If a user has not applied the jQuery tag, and you want to provide a jQuery solution, first ask in a comment if the OP is amenable to using jQuery.

Comment: @torazaburo ok i will do it .

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, sometimes jQuery makes it easy. But, many developers prefer to use the native JS syntaxes and do not use jQuery. It depends on your project, expectations and limitations. So, when someone is using native JavaScript for his/her project, we should try to solve his/her problem on the way is under used.

Comment: Yup, I didn't specify it in the question but I'm not looking for a jQuery solution. Thanks anyway!